# How do I assign cumbersome repetitive values to an array?

Tags: c

I want to create an array of 10 × 10, which contains `'.'` for each element. So I write as :

```
int A[10][10]={ '.','.','.','.',
```

(wait a minute I have to write 100 full stops and 100 commas)

```
               '.','.','.'}
```

Another method is to write `'.',` 10 times and then copy paste it 10 times, but still this takes time and I don't think this is the smartest method.

Is there a smarter method? I don't want to write so long full stops.

Comment: You might want to read up on loops.

Comment: @unwind The "c++ lounge" is [Lounge<C++>](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) (_in response to now-deleted [comment thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756630/how-do-i-assign-cumbersome-repetitive-values-to-an-array/30756668#comment49566536_30756668)_)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only feasible way to ***initialize*** an array like this, is (unfortunately) by using a flood of macros:

```
#define ONE_DOT '.',
#define TWO_DOTS ONE_DOT ONE_DOT
#define FIVE_DOTS TWO_DOTS TWO_DOTS ONE_DOT
#define TEN_DOTS { FIVE_DOTS FIVE_DOTS },
#define TWENTY_DOTS TEN_DOTS TEN_DOTS
#define FIFTY_DOTS TWENTY_DOTS TWENTY_DOTS TEN_DOTS
#define ONE_HUNDRED_DOTS FIFTY_DOTS FIFTY_DOTS


int A[10][10] = { ONE_HUNDRED_DOTS };
```

Comment: It almost looks like song lyrics.

Comment: @Quentin Feel free to use the code as lyrics for your next mainstream pop hit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop  statement to assign all elements to '.' ----

```
char A[10][10];
int i,j;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  for(j=0;j<10;j++)
     A[i][j]='.';
```

Comment: This isn't initialization, however. For example, what if A would be `const`?

Answer (score 1):

Loops are the thing You want to read about now.

The simple **for** loop will do that for you.

```
char A[10][10];
int i,j;
for ( i=0;i <10;++i){
     for ( j=0;j <10;++j)
            A[i][j]='.';
 }
```

For further justification google loops in c/c++

Comment: So, for each i between 0 and -1... well that's off to a good start.

Comment: @Quentin i is intiger type, what do u mean by between 0 and -1??

Comment: Your  `for` loops go from 0 included to 0 excluded, i.e [0, 0). They won't ever be entered.

Comment: Thats was a typo for 10 .... i honestly overlooked it.... Anyway i dont mind downvote to my answer but help me improve! Thanks

Comment: This isn't initialization, however. For example, what if A would be `const`?