# Const array initialization if its too long

Tags: c++, c

[In my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30756798/584518) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756630/how-do-i-assign-cumbersome-repetitive-values-to-an-array) it was mentioned that the code I posted wouldn't work if the variable was declared as `const`.

What if i want to initialize a long array that's `const` type

```
int main (){
    const int ar[100];
 //this is invalid in c++
 //something like this

    for (int i=0;i <100;++i)
        ar[i]=i;
    return 0;
}
```

Are there other ways to do this than using the [`#define` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757138/584518) proposed in that question?

Comment: Can you elaborate? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: @CoryKramer I think he's saying that he can't modify a const int[] after definition, therefore he can't initialize it.

Comment: `const int ar[100];` is not even legal C++, you cannot leave the array un-initialized

Comment: I suppose this is a follow-up question to my comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30756798/584518)? In that case, simply check the answer posted by yours sincerely to that question.

Comment: After declaring a const variable, you can no longer change its values. You should assign the values when you instantiate the object or variable.

Comment: @Lundin exactly,  but i dont find proper ans there.... if u dont mind kindly guide me

Comment: @SagarKar What part of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30757138/584518) didn't you understand? It is universal and applies to any data type, not just chars.

Comment: @Lundin ow u said about that #define method.... i mentioned that i am looking for something other than that... thats a cool method indeed

Comment: There is no standard way to do so. [Here is a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21528288/c-structure-array-initializing) with a very similar answer by me, plus some answers suggesting non-standard gcc extensions.

Comment: Thanks man! Nxt time i will try to post more meaningful question that dont go for downvote! @Lundin

Comment: This isn't a bad question, it is just very hard to understand for others what you mean, since you are referring to that other question, without posting a link to it. So nobody except me understood what you were asking :)

Comment: @Lundin will takecar form next time :)

Comment: I took the liberty to edit your question and post links.

Comment: @Lundin kudos to u.... bad deeds got me good teacher! ;)

Comment: you could also use templates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060103/create-static-array-with-variadic-templates

Comment: See [xxd](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xxd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do it directly, without hacks.

In C++ one way to work around this problem is to take advantage of the fact that inside their constructors `const` objects are still modifiable. So, you can wrap your array into a class and initialize it in the constructor

```
struct Arr 
{
  int a[100];

  A() 
  {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
      a[i] = i;
  }
};
```

and then just declare

```
const Arr arr;
```

Of course, now you will have to access it as `arr.a[i]`, unless you override the operators in `Arr`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a trick... initialize a regular array and then get a reference to a const array:

```
int arr[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) arr[i] = i*i;

const int (&carr)[100] = arr;
```

Comment: Cool thats somewhag cheating lol.... nice way though